How do I solve a first order ODE with an integrating factor that has both x and y?
The equation given is:
$$(3x^{2}y + 2)dx - (x^{3} + y)dy = 0$$
I've tried all the normal methods, the equation is not exact and not homogeneous either. The integrating factor is not a function of $x$ or $y$ alone, and by the looks of it, not a separable term either. When I assumed it was separable, I ended up with this equation, which does not seem to have a solution:
$$6x^{2} = (-x^{3} - y)p(x) - (3x^{2}y + 2)q(y)$$
Where $p(x)$ is a function of $x$ and $q(y)$, a function of $y$ (obviously). This has been driving me insane, I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

Is there a way to use an integrating factor to make it exact?

Are you sure there isn't anything with the constant $2$ other than $dx$?

DE can also be rewritten $d(x^3y+2x-\frac12 y^2)=2x^3dy$ not sure that helps though...

@Mike What other way is there to solve it?

@Gwen The equation is this exactly. No mistakes there.

You have the terms $3x^2y\,dx-x^3\,dy$ which proposes the substitution $y=x^3u$ as a way to simplify the expression. It might not work out, as there are two other terms in the equation. So replacing with $dy=3x^2u\,dx+x^3\,du$ gives
$$
0=(3x^5u+2)\,dx-x^3(1+u)\,(3x^2u\,dx+x^3\,du)
\\
=2\,dx -3x^5u^2\,dx-x^6(1+u)\,du.
$$
It looks slightly more as if it could be separable, but still no easy way forward.

$y=u-x^3$ also results in a simpler ode $\quad 6x^2u-uu'=3x^5-2\quad$ yet still not very appealing.

We are given the differential equation:
$$
(3x^2y + 2)dx - (x^3 + y)dy = 0
$$
We assume that the integrating factor is $$ \mu(x, y) = x^m y^n $$ Multiplying the original equation by this integrating factor, we get:
$$
x^m y^n \left( (3x^2y + 2)dx - (x^3 + y)dy \right) = 0
$$
Expanding both terms, we have:
$$
(3x^m y^n x^2y + 2x^m y^n) dx - (x^m y^n x^3 + x^m y^n y) dy = 0
$$
Simplifying:
$$
(3x^{m+2} y^{n+1} + 2x^m y^n)dx - (x^{m+3} y^n + x^m y^{n+1})dy = 0
$$
Thus, the equation becomes:
$$
(3x^{m+2} y^{n+1} + 2x^m y^n)dx - (x^{m+3} y^n + x^m y^{n+1})dy = 0
$$
Now consider the conditions for exactness
For the equation to be exact, the partial derivatives of the terms must satisfy the condition:
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}
$$
where
$$
M(x, y) = 3x^{m+2} y^{n+1} + 2x^m y^n
$$
and
$$
N(x, y) = -(x^{m+3} y^n + x^m y^{n+1}).
$$
We therefore compute the partial derivatives,
First, we compute $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} $:
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( 3x^{m+2} y^{n+1} + 2x^m y^n \right)
$$
$$
= 3x^{m+2}(n+1) y^n + 2x^m n y^{n-1}
$$
Then we compute $ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} $:
$$
\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( -(x^{m+3} y^n + x^m y^{n+1}) \right)
$$
$$
= -( (m+3)x^{m+2} y^n + m x^{m-1} y^{n+1} )
$$
Check if the partial derivatives are equal:
For the equation to be exact, the following must hold:
$$
3x^{m+2}(n+1) y^n + 2x^m n y^{n-1} = -( (m+3)x^{m+2} y^n + m x^{m-1} y^{n+1} )
$$
Let's match the powers of $ x $ and $ y $:
Matching Powers of $ x^{m+2} y^n $
For the terms involving $x^{m+2} y^n $, we have:
$$
3(n+1) = -(m+3)
$$
Solving for $ m $:
$$
3n + 3 = -m - 3 \implies m = -3n - 6
$$
Matching Powers of $ x^m y^{n+1}$
For the terms involving $x^m y^{n+1} $, we have:
$$
2n = -m
$$
Substituting $ m = -3n - 6  $ into this equation, we get:
$$
2n = -(-3n - 6)
$$
$$
2n = 3n + 6 \implies n = -6
$$
Solve for m
Now that we have $ n = -6 $, substitute it back into the equation for $ m$:
$$
m = -3(-6) - 6 = 18 - 6 = 12
$$
Thus, the integrating factor should be:
$$
\mu(x, y) = x^{12} y^{-6}
$$

There are no matching powers of $x^my^{n+1}$, you get $(m,n-1)$ on one side and $(m-1,n+1)$ on the other. So this seems if an integration factor exists, it is not of this form.

Strange. It looked good to me, even gave a solution.

Multiplying both the terms with this integrating factor isn't resulting in an exact solution, still. This isn't working.

You get an approximate solution, with an unknown constant C.
